# Facebook Analytics Active Users Tab - No Data

Tags: facebook-analytics

I have a live facebook app, with proper permissions (verified with Graph API).  I can create custom Dashboards with all the relevant data, and I get data in my Event Manager.

Current Permissions (Granted and Declined):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_birthday",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_likes",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_gender",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "email",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "declined"
    },
    {
      "permission": "read_insights",
      "status": "declined"
    }
```

What I'm having an issue with is with the "Active Users" tab under "Activity".  It keeps telling me there isn't enough data, however journeys for the same time period show over 17K journeys, my custom dashboards show similar numbers (19K) for impressions and logins.

What constitutes "Active Users" and why would I not be seeing anything under the Analytics component of the Analytics Explorer?

If there is another post or documentation that clarifies this, or if additional information is required, please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

"User Activity" or "Active Users" actually only looks at a few events, which are listed here: https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1747887018756757

If you're not logging any of those events, then you won't see any data under "Active Users."